# how by switching another page it should scroll down to specific block in that another page

Tags: jquery

I need that by clicking link it should redirect to another page and scroll down to specific block in that moment. How Can I relize that?

```
     <div class="row sidebar">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a  href="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/key-events');?>?num=2" class="keynote-block keynote-block-1"  id="1-area">
                    1 квартал
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a   href="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/key-events');?>?num=2" class="keynote-block keynote-block-2"   id="2-area">
                    2 квартал
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a  href="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/key-events');?>?num=2" class="keynote-block keynote-block-3"  id="3-area">
                    3 квартал
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a  href="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/key-events');?>?num=3" class="keynote-block keynote-block-4"  id="4-area">
                    4 квартал
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I was using something like that but it didn`t help me much

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    // Reove "link" from the ID
    id = id.replace("link", "");
    // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
$("#sidebar > div > a").click(function(e) {
    // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: [`anchors`](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.htm) are your friends. Just click then and it''ll take you whenever you want.

Comment: Do you need the animation or is it acceptable to just end up on the target page already scrolled to the appropriate position?  If you don't need the animation just do away with Javascript altogether and use anchors as @RompePC suggests.